# Name for categories with a certain property on coproducts

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, abelian-categories

Is there a name for categories with the following property:

The category has zero morphisms, coproducts, and for each family $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ of objects the natural map
$$\hom\bigl(Y,\coprod_{i \in I} X_i\bigr) \to \prod_{i \in I} \hom(Y,X_i),\quad f \mapsto (p_i \circ f)_{i \in I}$$
induced by the projections $p_i : \coprod_{i \in I} X_i \to X_i$ (defined by $p_i \circ \iota_i = \mathrm{id}$ and $p_i \circ \iota_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$), is an injective map.

In case the product $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ exists, the property means that the canonical morphism
$$\coprod_{i \in I} X_i \to \prod_{i \in I} X_i$$
is a monomorphism.

Examples are $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ and $\mathbf{Set}_*$. Not every abelian category has this property, but every AB5 category should be an example.

Comment: In some ways this is the complement of Bourn's notion of [unital category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unital+category), which asks for the canonical $X_0 + X_1 \to X_0 \times X_1$ to be a strong epimorphism.

Comment: This is just a restatement, but in a regular category this means that the coproduct coincides with the [direct sum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum).

Comment: What are the projections maps? In a generic category with coproducts there is no reason why you should have *natural* mappings from $\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i \to X_i$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The category is pointed, so you get morphisms by sending all the other summands to zero.

Comment: @ZhenLin if that's the case, well, it seems really hard to me that there are any interesting examples where the induced mappings between the hom-sets $\hom(Y,\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i)$ and $\prod_{i \in I}\hom(Y,X_i)$ are injective.......

Comment: Er, any category of modules is an example...

Comment: And $\mathsf{Top}_*$.